# How can I limit range of the thumbs in esri/dijit/TimeSlider

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, timeslider

From the [example](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer/), range between those two  thumbs is unlimited.

So, I need some thing like this

```
timeSlider.setThumbRangeLimit(1);  //one year
```

or something that limit the range only 1 year.

I have tried to use the [single thumb](http://jsbin.com/OpusenI/1) but it didn't work([Look at the `Time:` field](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSWells/MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png8&layers=show%3A0&time=-1546300800000%2C-599616000000&bbox=-11468792.455014436%2C4453312.282310774%2C-11051140.532464432%2C4593956.41435543&bboxSR=102100&imageSR=102100&size=1366%2C460&layerDefs=0%3AFIELD_KID%3D1000148164&f=html)). I think it needs the range for time.

So, do someone has any solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Can you use the "time-extent-change" event to ensure the range is only 1 year?

Answer (score 1):

The range between the two thumbs is whatever you specify (unless someone drags them around, but when a page loads, it's what you initially specify). In the sample, it's two years, as shown on this line:

```
timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 2, "esriTimeUnitsYears");
```

To create intervals of one year:

```
timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsYears");
```

Example:  http://jsbin.com/AxAFECi/1

The other option is to use:

```
timeSlider.setThumbCount(1);
timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsYears");
timeSlider.singleThumbAsTimeInstant(true);
```

This creates a slider with a single thumb and shows only data from one year at a time. The caveat here is that the dates in your data must must be at the same point in time if you want them to display during the same year. Here's an example with the well data, since the dates in that data vary, the only year for which you'll see any wells is 2001:  http://jsbin.com/ovuFAZa/2

Comment: Thanks Derek. But this is not I need. I mean I have to limit the range between two thumbs. Example. The limit is 1 year. So user can't drag the thumb over 1 year. The range between two thumbs must be 1 year. Not allow to drag over 1 year.